# Does the exists invertible matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}\operatorname{diag}(A,B)S=\operatorname{diag}(B,A)$ with $\det(S)=1.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m$ by $m$ matrix, and $B$ be an $n$ by $n$ matrix. I know that
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&I_n\\I_m&0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} A&0\\0&B \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0&I_m\\I_n&0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} B&0\\0&A \end{bmatrix}.$$
But $\det\biggl(\begin{bmatrix} 0&I_m\\I_n&0 \end{bmatrix}\biggr)$ may not equal to $1$. I want to know whether there is an invertible matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}\operatorname{diag}(A,B)S=\operatorname{diag}(B,A)$ with $\det(S)=1.$

Comment: Try an example with $1\times 1$-matrices $A$ and $B$, to see how it works. It is easy to find such $S$, except for degenerate cases.

Comment: The det of that matrix is either 1 or -1. See if you can go from here

Comment: This is easy if we can find a matrix $C$ such that $\det(C) = -1$ and either $AC = CA$ or $BC = CB$. It is "rare" that no such $C$ exists, but we can see that no such $C$ exists for
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}, \quad B = 2A.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\det\pmatrix{0&I_n\\ I_m&0}=(-1)^{mn}$, if $mn$ is even, the matrix already has determinant $1$. If $mn$ is odd, then both $m$ and $n$ are odd and you may consider $S=\pmatrix{0&-I_n\\ I_m&0}$ instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I have another question here. I know that $det\begin{bmatrix} 0&I_n\\I_m&0 \end{bmatrix}=(-1)^{mn}$  by switching their rows, so if $m=n$, $det\begin{bmatrix} 0&I_n\\I_n&0 \end{bmatrix}=(-1)^{n^2}$. But from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices), I know $det\begin{bmatrix} 0&I_n\\I_n&0 \end{bmatrix}=det(00-I_nI_n)=-1$. Is there something wrong here?

Comment: I try $n=2$, I found that $det\begin{bmatrix} 0&I_n\\I_n&0 \end{bmatrix}\neq det(00-I_nI_n)= -1$.

Comment: @魚水水 $\det(00-I_nI_n)=\det(-I_n)=(-1)^n$.

Comment: Thank you! I found my mistake!